# Filter a Multi-Type Lookup Field in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a lookup field of type Number with the following row source:

```
SELECT Cohort.[pkCohortID], [fkProgramID] & " " & [CohortNumber] AS Expr2 FROM Cohort;
```

Its Display Control is Combo Box.

[pkCohortID] is of type AutoNumber.

[fkProgramID] is of type ShortText.

[CohortNumber] is of type Short Text.

I would like to extract the [fkProgramID] portion and filter it using "Like %record%" via a SQL query. Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very clear about the problem in your question so I make some assumption to make this answer

First of all before any assumption wildcard in access is **"*"** not **"%"**
so your query should be

```
 SELECT Cohort.[pkCohortID], [fkProgramID] & " " & [CohortNumber] AS Expr2 
      FROM Cohort
      WHERE [fkProgramID] LIKE '*record*';
```

Next I assume you want to filter the Combo Box's row source with value from specific record from Form's Record Source then you will need vba for updating Combo Box's row source every time the record changed..
Let's say th

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Combo2.RowSource = "SELECT Cohort.[pkCohortID], [fkProgramID] & 
    ' ' & [CohortNumber] AS Expr2 FROM Cohort WHERE [fkProgramID] LIKE '*" 
    & Something & "*'"
End Sub
```

for further clearance I suggest you to rephrase your question and make the problem more specific and easy to understand